# could not open file bin/magento in magento 2 ssh

Tags: magento2, extensions, marketplace, upload, ssh

after uploading my marketplace-module in

> app/code

i've run the command as

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

but it gave me the following error as shown in image :
[image]

i checked the file permission of magento in

> bin/magento
>   it is set to 0755
>   after that i tried to change the permission to 0777
>   but no chnage im still getting this error

```
could not open the file bin/magento
```

can anoyone tell me what is going wrong from my side?
thanks in advance.

Comment: run this command from magento root folder

Comment: how? im using this command from ssh... how to navigate to magento root folder? i dont have much knowledge about that

Comment: how did you uploaded that marketplace module?

Comment: i've bought that module and then uploaded it in app/code after that i run the command

Comment: i've also tried using `composer require mydoule:moduleVersion`
but that further gave me the following error 
`Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package medma/module-marketplace could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   and more`

Comment: ok type pwd command in your ssh and sent that path.. I'll tell that root path

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73931/discussion-between-jeeva-chezhiyan-and-laiba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate in putty try to use Midnight Commander.

1. install package `sudo apt install mc`
2. type `mc`
3. navigate to magento root directory (basically is /var/www/...)

or use [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php)